# How to use face culling and depth test in pyopengl

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

I am working on a program for school that uses 3D shapes and I need to figure out how to make a solid cube. When I make the cube I end up with this:[image]

I noticed that it is drawing the shapes in the order that I defined them. I then tried to find a solution to this problem because I am sure many other people have a similar problem and I run into something called face culling which has all the faces points be defined counterclockwise when facing out so when it is rendered it would be drawn clockwise and opengl can notice that and not draw them.
I tried using this and It still ended up with the same result so I am confused about what I have done wrong.

```
import pygame
import time
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

block = [
    [0,1,0],
    [1,0,0],
    [1,0,1],
    [0,0,1],
    [1,1,0],
    [0,1,1]
]

def Cube(x,y,z):
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
    glColor3f(block[0][0], block[0][1], block[0][2])  # N
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glColor3f(block[1][0], block[1][1], block[1][2])  # S
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glColor3f(block[2][0], block[2][1], block[2][2])  # W
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glColor3f(block[3][0], block[3][1], block[3][2])  # E
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glColor3f(block[4][0], block[4][1], block[4][2])  # U
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glColor3f(block[5][0], block[5][1], block[5][2])  # D
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y, z + .5)
    glEnd()
def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (800,600)
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glClearDepth(1.0)

    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
    glCullFace(GL_BACK)
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW)
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
    glDepthRange(0.0,1.0)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
    gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 100.0)
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)
    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        glRotatef(1, 3, 1, 1,)
        glClearDepth(1.0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        Cube(0,0,0)
        glCullFace(GL_BACK)
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(.01)




main()
```

Comment: why not use `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);`?

Comment: As @Spektre said, this isn't so much a face culling issue as it is a depth test issue. Maybe this is the wanted result, but without depth test your faces will be drawn in the order you defined them, and if you have 2 cubes then the back cube might be rendered on top of the front one.

Comment: @florentteppe The depth test is enabled (`glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`). The image doesn't correspond to the code!

Comment: @Rabbid76 unless wrong combination of text function and clear depth value was used...

Comment: @Rabbid76 heh another typo should be Test function for the depth instead of text :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (OpenGL) display mode has been set, before any OpenGL instruction is called, else it won't have any effect or even cause an error:

```py
pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
glClearDepth(1.0)

glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
glCullFace(GL_BACK)
glFrontFace(GL_CCW)
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
glDepthRange(0.0,1.0)
```

If you do so, the the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) will work and the mesh is drawn correctly.

---

By the way not all of the faces are drawn with counter clockwise winding order. It has to be:

```py
def Cube(x,y,z):
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
    glColor3f(block[0][0], block[0][1], block[0][2])  # N
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y,     z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y,     z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y,     z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glColor3f(block[1][0], block[1][1], block[1][2])  # S
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y,     z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y,     z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y,     z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glColor3f(block[2][0], block[2][1], block[2][2])  # W
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y,     z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y,     z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y,     z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glColor3f(block[3][0], block[3][1], block[3][2])  # E
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y,     z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y,     z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y,     z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glColor3f(block[4][0], block[4][1], block[4][2])  # U
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glColor3f(block[5][0], block[5][1], block[5][2])  # D
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y, z - .5)
    glEnd()
```